# What is the flow of this block of code

Tags: java, android, break, continue

I'm having difficulty in understanding this block of code, The `continue` statement confuses me.

Note that `activityArray` is the array of string whereas `paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel` is returning some `String`.

```
private float calculateWater(UserInfo paramUserInfo)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[0])) {
        i = 0;
    }

    for (;;){
       try{ 
            int k = Integer.parseInt(this.weight.getText().toString().trim().trim());
            j = k;
        }
        catch (Exception localException){     
            continue; 
        }

        if (!paramUserInfo.Unit.equals("Kgs")) {
            continue; 
        }
        return (j * 2.202F * 2.0F / 3.0F + i * 0.0338F) * 29.57F;

        if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[1])) {
            i = 175;
        } else if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[2])) {
            i = 530;
        } else if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[3])) {
            i = 700; 
        }   
    }

    return (int)j * 2 / 3 + i * 0.0338F; 
}
```

Comment: There is no `continue` statement in the code you've shown us

Comment: Also, formatting the code nicer will help you understand it better!

Comment: Stack overflow wont let me format nicer because i was having error too much code

Comment: @blackHawk [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44701529/edit) and fix the indentation. Honestly, Stack Overflow will not prevent you having correctly indented code.

Comment: Thank you @Dayan for editing

Comment: Why is it calling the trim() method twice..? Also it should catch a NumberFormatException instead of a Exception

Comment: @blackHawk Please make sure to accept an answer if you found that it helped you understand it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Continue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_continue_statement.htm) is used to skip the current iteration and move on to the next.

[image]

So take this part of your code as an example:

```
try{ 
    int k = Integer.parseInt(this.weight.getText().toString().trim().trim());
    j = k;
}
catch (Exception localException){     
    continue; //Do not execute anything else, go to next iteration.
}
```

If an exception is caught, it will ignore it and simply move to the next iteration.

You have to be very careful here because, this infinite for-loop, hence `for(;;)` doesn't have time to breath. If you are attempting to run this piece of code on the Main thread it will crash.

Include `Thread.sleep(0,2)` if you want it to run fast, and make sure that this is running on its own thread.

**Aside from that, there are many things wrong with this code.**

1 - The last return statement will never execute because there is no `break` in the `for-loop`; break lets you step out of the loop. So, `return (int)j * 2 / 3 + i * 0.0338F;` won't ever execute.

2 - There is no need to call `trim()` twice, as you did here - `int k = Integer.parseInt(this.weight.getText().toString().trim().trim());`.

3 - When doing string comparisons, use `compareToIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals`. `paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[1])`. Like so, 
`paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.compareToIngoreCase(this.activityArray[1]) == 0`.

4 - When dealing with exception handling, try not to catch all. In the example above, you can simply catch `NumberFormatException` instead of `Exception`.  [Read this!](https://source.android.com/source/code-style)

Answer (score 0):

if program reads continue code, then your program go back to the beginning of for(;;)

this part will not work if a continue code works

```
return (j * 2.202F * 2.0F / 3.0F + i * 0.0338F) * 29.57F;

    if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[1])) {
        i = 175;
    } else if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[2])) {
        i = 530;
    } else if (paramUserInfo.ActivityLevel.equals(this.activityArray[3])) {
        i = 700; 
    }
```